# Sub Views are not visible after change the UILabel Background colour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have changed my `UILabel` background colour like this. Actually I have added an image to it. I did it like this.

```
self.lblMsg=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8.0, self.lblDateTime.frame.origin.y+self.lblDateTime.frame.size.height, size.width-5.0, 100.0)];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"msgBackground"];
    CGSize imgSize = self.lblMsg.frame.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( imgSize );
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,imgSize.width,imgSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.lblMsg.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.lblMsg];
```

Now I want to add another `UILabel`on to this and that label should include an image as an attachment. So I did it like this.

```
self.lblWeatherTitle=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.lblMsg.frame.size.width, 50.0)];

    NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
    attachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splashLogo"];

    NSAttributedString *attachmentString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];

    NSMutableAttributedString *myString= [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"My label text"];
    [self.lblWeatherTitle setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [myString appendAttributedString:attachmentString];

    self.lblWeatherTitle.attributedText = myString;
    [self.lblMsg addSubview:self.lblWeatherTitle];
```

But My 2nd `UILabel` is not visible.

This is what I need to do
[image]

This black text is a long description. As the title of it it should show those red label and the yellow icon. so I added that top label as a subview to this white label. This whole thing is inside a custom `UITableViewCell`

Please help me. How can I do this in correct way?
Thanks

Comment: This is how I debug this kind of issue: My subviews (say 3 UILabels) to be added in another UILabel (parent). Every label have their unique color, red for label at the top-left side, orange at the top-right side, and yellow color at the bottom. If I see my subviews is in the correct position, then that's the time I customize my UILabe (parent) to what I really wanted. Hope this helps to debug your problem, investigate, it's a matter of how you position your controls.

Comment: can you log your label's position?